# Django - get model object in .values() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have this table:

| Seller Name | Sale date |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 2023/05/01 |
| Bob | 2023/05/03 |
| Alice | 2023/05/15 |
| Alice | 2023/05/31 |
| Carl | 2023/05/01 |
| Carl | 2023/05/04 |
| Bob | 2023/05/20 |
| Carl | 2023/05/21 |

and I am using this Django queryset to have first and last sale date of each seller:

```py
sales = (Sale.objects.filter(created_at__year=2023, created_at__month=5)
            .values('seller')
            .annotate(min_date=Min('created_at'), max_date=Max('created_at'))
            .order_by()
)
```

The query works correctly, but it returns the `id` of the seller instead of the `<Seller>` object:

```json
{'seller': 1, 'min_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 1, 3, 52, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'max_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 31, 7, 32, 1, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
{'seller': 2, 'min_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 3, 4, 34, 11, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'max_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 20, 5, 52, 1, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
{'seller': 3, 'min_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 1, 11, 50, 5, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'max_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 21, 10, 21, 1, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

How can I get `Seller` model object in queryset?

**UPDATE:** this is the relevant code of my `models.py` file

```py
class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class Sale(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select_related` to fetch the related Seller objects. Here's an updated version of your query

```
sales = (Sale.objects.filter(created_at__year=2023, created_at__month=5)
         .select_related('seller')
         .values('seller')
         .annotate(min_date=Min('created_at'), max_date=Max('created_at'))
         .order_by()
)
```

Comment: Hi tried your query but it keeps showing only seller id. I've updated my question with my `models.py` code.